# Allowing user to only type in next available text field in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

New to Swift and xcode here. I am trying to make a simple to-do planner using a tableview and tableview cells in swift.

I was wondering if there is any way to make it so that when a user clicks on any text field, the text field to respond should be the next available text field only.

[image]

For example in this photo, if a user clicks on like the 10th text field, the text field that should open up should only be the 4th one, the one after the "homework" cell.

Is this something simple to do, or am I way over my head here?

Any other tips are appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you want multiple text fields for your usecase?

Comment: right now i am just using one text field which works fine, but would I need to have multiple text fields to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `UITableView`'s `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. You will be able know selected row's `indexPath`. I assume that you have a data as array which is being used to load `tableView`'s data. In that `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method you can simply check the `indexPath` of selected row and your data count. If they match then do nothing, If not you can use `tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(:_)` to select the right cell -according to your example, the 4th one-. I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `textFieldShouldReturn` from `UITextFieldDelegate` if dealing only with textFields

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField != lastTextField{
        self.lastTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    return true
}
```

or for table with custom cells :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row != lastItemRow + 1{
        let cellToFocus = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        cellToFocus.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Comment: what should lastTextField and/or lastItemRow be?

Comment: @brownmamba lastTextField refers to last object from list of textfield objects in the view. From what you mentiond you need the second approach so : lastItemRow refers to last index of your fetched items. Suppose there is todoItems = [Foo](), lastItem = todoItems.count